# MongoDB Scala driver including specific fields from embedded documents

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query

In a MongoDB query, it's possible to aggregate and include specific fields from embedded documents.

[MongoDB manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) section: Include Specific Fields from Embedded Documents

Example query:

```
db.getCollection('test')
.aggregate([ 
    { $project : { "name" : "$subLevel.name" , _id: 1 } }
])
```

So a document like:

```
{
    "_id": "id1",
    "sublevel":{
        "name": "name1"
    }
}
```

is aggregated to:

```
{
    "_id": "id1",
    "name": "name1"
}
```

However, I can't find the option to do this with the mongoDB Scala driver.
[org.mongodb.scala.model.Projections](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-scala-driver/1.0/scaladoc/#org.mongodb.scala.model.Projections$)

Does somebody have an idea on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to not using the Projections, but to specify the json that it would generate directly and create a Document with it.

```
val project = Document(Json.obj("$project" -> Json.obj("name" -> "$subLevel.name")).toString)
val `match` = Document(Json.obj("$match" -> Json.obj("name" -> "item1")).toString)

collection.aggregate(Seq(project, `match`))
```